# Why does hotspot use different assembly styles in same source code?

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, inline-assembly, jvm-hotspot

For example, hotspot uses at&t and intel style to describe the `fence()` function.

[image]

Since both at&t and intel style assembly have the same underlying machine code, why does hotspot use different styles in the same source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HotSpot for Windows is compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC).
HotSpot for Linux is compiled with GCC.

MSVC and GCC indeed have different syntax for inline assembly.

Comment: Why not just use gcc? Does msvc has anything that gcc could not achieve?

Comment: That is a different question.  But I imagine that the (originally) reasons included the fact that the Microsoft supported MSVC and not GCC on Windows.

Comment: @StephenC do you mean that MinGw was not supported at that time?

Comment: No.  I am talking about the compiler.  (MinGW isn't supported by Windows either.  I don't know how Java for Windows was built prior to the open-sourcing of Java.  But I doubt that they used MinGW to do it.  Either way MinGW doesn't include Microsoft's compilers, so that would not explain why the source code uses Windows assembler syntax.)

Comment: gcc also support intel-style assembly by adding compile parameters, why not just use intel-style?

Comment: Another reason will be ... "if it ain't broken, don't fix it".

Comment: GCC didn't always support intel syntax (HotSpot appeared in 1999). After all, using the native syntax for the particular platform is quite logical, why bother inventing something different?

Comment: @scottxiao: `gcc -masm=intel` I think come more recently than the start of the Hotspot project.  It still doesn't come close to unifying the overall syntax: GNU C `asm("template" : outputs : inputs : clobbers)`  vs. MSVC `asm { block }`, and most projects that use GNU C inline asm use it with the default AT&T syntax so the code works without special compile options.  (Or with dialect alternatives so it works with either `-masm=intel` or `att`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Multiple-assembler-dialects-in-asm-templates)